# Erro ao conectar a base de dados remota

Tags: c#, mysql

Boa noite, estou tendo problemas com o seguinte contexto:

`MySql`

Utilizando a linha de código abaixo eu tentei conectar a um servidor de mysql remoto para tentar acessar algumas tabelas e vem o seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que já tentei de tudo e até agora não consegui nenhum resultado com o cógido abaixo:

```
public bool IsLogged;
        public string username;
        public string UAC_L;
        public int id;

        MySqlConnection myconnection;

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn;
conn = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn.Server = "mysql2.000webhost.com";
conn.UserID = "a1478344_app";
conn.Password = "SENHA!";
conn.Port = 3306;

myconnection = new MySqlConnection(conn.ToString());
myconnection.Open(); // O Erro ocorre aqui!

#region !OBFUSCATED!
MySqlCommand command_login = myconnection.CreateCommand();
command_login.CommandText = "SELECT usr_id,usr_rname,usr_UASC FROM `a1478344_app`.`app_users` WHERE usr_email=`@email` AND usr_password=`@senha`"
command_login.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email_t.Text);
command_login.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", Base64.Base64Encode(senha_t.Text));

MySqlDataReader reader = command_login.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
id = reader.GetInt32("usr_id");
username = reader.GetString("usr_rname");
UAC_L = reader.GetString("usr_UASC");

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("O Usuário {0} tem o ID {1} com privilégios de {2}", username, id, UAC_L));
myconnection.Close();
}
#endregion
```

O erro acontece quando depois que eu insiro os dados da `ConnectionString` e aplico o método `myconnection.Open();`

E o código desse erro é um tal de `1042` conforme o MySqlException.Number.
Solution Explorer com as referências usadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza que as informações de conexão com o banco de dados estão corretas? Pergunto apenas para excluir esta hipótese :)

Comment: Sim estão sim! conferi e tudo! mas do mesmo jeito fica esse erro!

Comment: Uma dúvida a solution explorer está certo?

Comment: Você conferiu se você realmente consegue conectar-se manualmente ao servidor `mysql2.000webhost.com`? Digo, mesmo que as credenciais estejam corretas, pode existir algum problema ao conectar da sua máquina ao servidor.

Comment: sim ele é o servidor do mysql do 000webhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se o seu banco mysql tem [permissão para conexão remota](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348506/2387977) de usuários.

Este comando garantirá este acesso vindo de qualquer IP (`@'%'`) para o usuário *a1478344_app* para qualquer banco de dados (`*.*`).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON *.*
TO 'a1478344_app'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'SENHA!';
```

Comment: vou tentar agora...

Comment: ops! deu um erro Error

SQL query: 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON DATABASE . *  TO 'a1478344_app'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword' 

MySQL said: Documentation 
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database.*
 TO 'a1478344_app'@'%'
 IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword'' at line 2

Comment: eu executei como se fosse mysql_query

Comment: Corrigido. Tente novamente.

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'a1478344_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: e agora o que pode ter causado isso? Deixa eu te perguntar se você souber um site que hospede mysql gratuitamente

Comment: apareceu mais um erro __#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SENHA!'  at line 1__

Comment: Estou desconfiado que o 000webhost não aceita conexões remotas sem upgrade da conta: http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27.

Comment: eita! não sabia que só contra premium podia! e agora como irei fazer o sistema de login/cadastro no meu app...

Comment: ainda bem que você me amostrou esse link!

Comment: você por acaso não conhece um servidor que hospede mysql com acesso remoto?

Comment: outra coisa, eu tenho um pc antigo, mas que funciona, então como eu faria para poder configura o Windows server 2008 r2 nele para hospedar servidores de games e sites?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço um site bom que hospede gratuitamente um banco de dados MySQL. Eu tentaria configurar um banco MySQL na sua própria máquina, se isto for possível para você.

Comment: :(    bem desde já agradeço! pois se não fosse você eu nem ia saber que o 000webhost não tinha acesso remoto!

Comment: Dherik... O Banco de dados da Microsoft sql server é muito difícil de se trabalhar ou é o mesmo que mysql? e o banco de dados da Microsoft sql server é permitido em php?

Comment: O uso básico é bem similar, você não terá dificuldades se já conhece MySQL. Sim, pode usar o Sql Server com PHP normalmente.